Не получается установить Unity 3D через Unity Hub


Пытаюсь установить unity 3D через Unity Hub. Процесс установки останавливается на validating. Установить движок получается только напрямую с сайта, но тогда не устанавливаются пакеты SDK, NDK, JDK
